# Password is displayed as text in the admin panel (not hashed)

Tags: python, django

There is a `CustomUser` model inherited from `AbstractUser`. When registering a model in the admin panel, the password is displayed as text, that is, the type of this field is `text`, not `password`. I know that this problem can be solved if, together with the model, the `ModelAdmin` class is registered, in my case it will be `CustomUserAdmin` inherited from `UserAdmin` from `django.contrib.auth.admin`, and the password will be displayed correctly, but then the fields from `CustomUser` will not be displayed (as if the `CustomUser` model is registered, but only the fields of the User model will be displayed, when using a class inherited from the above-mentioned `UserAdmin`). What to do with this, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

you need to import django's function "make_password" if you need make a password:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
```

and when you save the password in the db, do the following:

```
password=make_password(form.cleaned_data['password']),
```

django has already declared field for password user, you dont need to declared it again in the model that inherits AbstractUser.